# Family Sharing screen time shows black screen

Tags: ios, family-sharing

Can I set screen time settings for my child's ipad from iPhone with ios 13?
Family Sharing is set up, I am the coordinator, child has kid's icloud account. The problem is that when I goto My Account -> Family Sharing -> Screen Time I get blank screen. Family members are visible on prev page.

Comment: I think you have to first enable sharing the usage time on the ScreenTime configuration, then it will show under Family Sharing

Comment: I have the same issue. My Screen Time is being shared. Did you ever figure out how to solve this?